# Looker report for big query job performance

Tags: google-bigquery, jobs, looker-studio

I would like to create a report on `job performance in big query` in looker. Can anyone suggest what type of graphs I can create?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are looking to use the job performance for its hard to answer, I always us this flowchart to help me choose a graph type
https://www.perceptualedge.com/blog/?p=2080 it was made for excel graphs but the logic is still good